# Typing "powershell" in explorer adress bar stopped working

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-explorer, windows-11

I was used to type "powershell" or "cmd" ind adress bar of windows explorer.
While "cmd" is still working: it's opening cmd on current folder:

"powershell" stopped working instead of opening a powershell its opening the folder "documents/powershell" (with my powershell profile inside).

I am not sure if this is related to a windows update or some kind of configuration change. I am using Powershell 7 installed with winget.

side note: "powershell_ise" is also working

Comment: Seems Explorer uses the first match, which is the user's `PowerShell` folder. When you append `.exe` it's working. Or hit the `WIN` key or `WIN + R` and enter `powershell` / `pwsh` (pwsh for PowerShell Core / 6+).

Comment: Command Prompt (cmd) and PowerShell are two entirely different consoles. Have you tried to reinstall PowerShell 7? PowerShell 5.1 is built-into Windows 11 cannot be uninstalled but it’s a side-by-side installation of PowerShell. The reason the legacy version of PowerShell isn’t working cannot be determined by the information you provided

Comment: i am aware, but both cmd and powershell worked fine before @swbbl "pwsh" is working fine - make this an answer!

Comment: There are more solutions in [Windows Terminal's wt.exe cannot be found for non-admin user's PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63303785/3416774)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `powershell` command is not for PowerShell 7, it's used to refer to older versions (`5.1` and below) rather. `pwsh` is what you need to type to be sure to open the right executable - it shouldn't normally have conflicts with any directories either, at least my installation can't see any with lots of various applications installed.

Secondly, the address bar opens apps with its own algorithm that e.g. prefers the contents of the currently open directory and I believe also the first entries it can find by scanning dirs alphabetically, starting from `This PC` listed directories like `Desktop` and `Documents`, after some testing. It's not quite a reliable place to open executables, as any random Windows update might change it. It's the first time I'm seeing someone using that to open apps.

Alternatives (that are also faster and more comfortable IMO) include but aren't limited to:

- setting up a hotkey with [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/), for instance
- adding context menu entries, some terminal apps like [ConEmu](https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu) implement that by themselves
  [image: ConEmu entries]
- adding a button to the Explorer toolbars with e.g. [QTTabBar](http://qttabbar.wikidot.com/)